# how to optimize storage problem in magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, image, optimization

> magento ver 2.2.6
>
> i have 2,000 products but
>
> storage 16GB (pub/media folder 14GB)
>
> how i can optimize this storage problem..

Comment: when you replace image for Any of your product or catagory it remains in pub/media folder such media files increase your storage
try to use image cleaner extension

Comment: try this https://www.fmeextensions.com/magento-2-image-clean-extension-delete-unused-images.html